# Recursively compare an integer to a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am writing a Haskell function that recursively compares an integer `i` to a list of tuples. In particular, I want to compare integer `i` to each `a` in `(a,b)` in the list. If `i < a` then print the `b` that corresponds with the `a`

Sample input/output

```
check 0.01 [(0.25, 'x'),(0.50,'y'),(0.75,'z')] = 'x'
check 0.4 [(0.25, 'x'),(0.50,'y'),(0.75,'z')] = 'y'
check 100 [(0.25, 'x'),(0.50,'y'),(0.75,'z')] = ' '
```

I wrote a pseudocode on how I would approach it but I'm having trouble translating that pseudocode to a actual Haskell function. Here is what I have so far:

```
check :: a -> [(a,b)] -> b
check i (a,b):xs = tuples d xs
    | if d <= a in (a,b) then = b //pseudocode
    | id d !<= a in (a,b) then recursively check the next tuple //pseudocode
    | otherwise ' ' // d is larger than all the a's of the tuple so return a space
```

I believe the way I'm thinking about it is correct but I can't figure out how to traverse through the tuples comparing the integer `i` to the `a`s of the tuples. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some points to note :

- You can not return a number like `1` and a character like `' '` together in the same function because they are of different types. What you can do insted is to use `Maybe b` to return `Nothing` where you wanted to return `' '` and `Just 1` where you wanted to return `1`.
- Since you are doing comparisons on type `a` hence you need `a` to belong to `Ord` type class.

So your modified program becomes

```
check :: (Ord a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
check d [] = Nothing
check d ((a,b):xs) | d <= a = Just b
                 | otherwise = check d xs
```

Trying out the function in ghci gives

```
> check 0.01 [(0.25, 1),(0.50,2),(0.75,3)]
Just 1
> check 0.4 [(0.25, 1),(0.50,2),(0.75,3)]
Just 2
> check 100 [(0.25, 1),(0.50,2),(0.75,3)]
Nothing
```

You can also use `find` from `Data.List` to write your function which has type

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

So your function check becomes

```
check2 :: (Ord a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
check2 a = fmap snd . find ((> a) . fst)
```

(Edit) Changes according to edited question

```
check :: (Ord a) => a -> [(a,Char)] -> Char
check d [] = ' '
check d ((a,b):xs) | d <= a = b
                   | otherwise = check d xs
```

To be able to use original check function you can also use `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`

```
newCheck ::  Ord a => a -> [(a, Char)] -> Char
newCheck d xs = fromMaybe ' ' $ check d xs
```

Comment: okay that makes sense. since you pointed out that they don't return the same type, could be this still be done if they were to all return Char. I edited the sample output to reflect that idea

Comment: @NuNu Given any fixed type, you can combine this solution with `fromMaybe defaultValue` to get the desired result. The function `fromMaybe` is available from `Data.Maybe`.

Comment: @NuNu I added what you wanted.

Comment: @Satvik Thanks I see the difference now. Thanks for the explanations

Comment: Good explanation.  More tersely: `check d = maybe ' ' snd . find ((d <=) . fst)`